# Is there a minimum amount of fields to justify using form tag in angular?

Tags: html, forms, angular, user-input

I'm creating a site with login form (only username and password input fields) and I was wandering **what's the best-practice** for form in angular4?

Comment: can you refine your question. I can't understand

Comment: There is no minimal amount of fields. Ok, there is a minimum: `1` ;-)
You don't need to use a `<form>` tag for input field bindings using `ngModel`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I do want to use validation that form tag has.
I d'ont HAVE to use form, I just want to know whats the best practice to use forms.

Comment: I don't think there is much to it. There is a section about forms in https://angular.io/docs. There are no general best practices. If you have a concrete problem it might be easier to provide support.

Comment: Forms are just a way to structure your data. You can do just fine without forms but then you would need to have multiple properties bind to inputs and write some logic for each input validation  and make validations work together. I would say, if number of inputs > 1 and it should look like form in the UI then use forms.

Comment: @mikedanylov tnx!!